# Wait until the nth element with the same name is clickable

Tags: python, selenium

How to wait until the nth element with the same name is clickable, and then click it,  with selenium EC?

The website looks like this: 
[image]
I want to click every 'tr' class in a for loop. But I got this error:
[image]

I tried
`WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='table-list']//tr[.]"[i])))` but it does not work. So, how to wait until the nth element with the same name is clickable?

I think I am pretty close, but cannot figure it out. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are almost there. Here is the correct line.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//table[@class='table-list']//tr)[i]")))
```

`[i]` should be with in the double quotes.